# Chained task is not executed thourgh specified queue when workers are concurrent

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I'd like to apply queue settings to chained tasks. Here's sample tasks.

```
from celery import chain
from task.calc import *

def execute(some, some2):
    return chain(add_1.s(some, some2, 10), add_2.s).apply_async()
```

Here's celeryconfig specify queue settings.

```
class MyRouter():
    def route_for_task(self, task, args=None, kwargs=None):
        if 'task.calc' in task:
            return {
                'queue': 'calc',
                'exchange': 'calc',
                'exchange_type': 'topic',
                'routing_key': 'direct'
            }

CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('calc', Exchange('calc', type='topic'), routing_key='calc'),
)
CELERY_ROUTES = (
    MyRouter()
)
```

When I runs celery worker with below command, chained task is executed properly.

```
$ celery worker -A task -P eventlet -Q calc
```

But when I runs celery worker with concurrent workers, chained task is not executed, but executed just first task(`task.calc.add_1`).

```
$ celery worker -A task -P eventlet -Q calc -c 32
```

Is there any tips to use celery workers with concurrent mode and queue.

Comment: by default celery runs in concurrent mode - if you do not specify `-c` it defaults to the number of cores. How many cores are on your machine? Can you check `ps` output to see how many worker processes are running when you use the first command?

Comment: Just one process runs when I run celery without -c. Thanks.

Comment: you only have 1 core, correct? (if not then something odd is going on). what does the celery output show? have you tried omitting `-P eventlet`? you should be able to access the subtasks inside your chain (`parent`, `children` etc) - what state are these in ? what is your broker? if rabbitmq you can enable the web interface to get an insight into what is happening with your requests

Comment: It's correct because I run celery on virtual machine with 1 core. I use rabbitmq as broker. Task state is 'PENDING' when I runs execute method and if I try to command with task_result.get(), that's never returns result(Worker also not respond).

Comment: try removing `-P eventlet`. can you make your task output detailed logging so you can see if it runs. what do the celery logs say?